# CastleWindsor 3.0 and DefaultServiceHostFactory.RegisterContainer()?

Tags: castle-windsor, wcffacility, windsor-3.0

The following does not compile:

DefaultServiceHostFactory.RegisterContainer(Container.Kernel);

The static method does not seem to exist in Castle 3.0 - I checked the breakingchanges.txt and did not see this listed.

What am I missing?

Comment: This is the 3.0 equivalent:

Container.Register(Component.For<DefaultServiceHostFactory>());

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You don't need the call any more as it gets registered when you wire up the facility.

```cs
container.AddFacility<WcfFacility>();
```

Is all you need, sweet :)

This is not required:

```
DefaultServiceHostFactory.RegisterContainer(Container.Kernel);
```

nor is this

```
Container.Register(Component.For<DefaultServiceHostFactory>());
```